# Получить исходный код страницы, который хранится в javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

Есть [страница](http://steamcommunity.com/economy/itemhover/730/2/2469335601?o=76561198128993500), с которой нужно получить то, что выводится на экран, а именно, в атрибуте с классом `hover_item_name`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пользуюсь обычным `XMLHttpRequest();`, но он ничего не выводит.

Оказывается, все данные хранятся в *js* внизу страницы.

[image: Не придумал...]

Меня же интересует только выделенный фрагмент массива:

[image: Тоже не придумал...]

Как получить этот "Элемент"?

Comment: Вы пишите расширение в браузере? Это я к тому что тег "chrome-extension" тут присутствует.

Comment: Да. Думал, может какие-то функции есть для этого в chrome api.

Comment: Что мешает вам распарсить содержимое тега `script` ?

Comment: Мешает то что я не знаю как. Прошу помощи !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самым простым вариантом распарсить содержимое  в этой ситуации мне видится через использование [регулярных выражений](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), т.к. по сути это одна большая строка. И благодаря тому, что вам заранее известен ключ нужного параметра, то сделать это можно достаточно просто с помощью следующего регулярного выражения:

```
/"market_hash_name":"(.*?)"/
```

Искомая подстрока должна начинаться с `"market_hash_name":"` и заканчиваться `"`, при этом мы хотим отдельно захватить то, что находится внутри кавычек, что можно сделать с помощью `(.*?)`, где `.` - любой символ, `*` - повторяется любое количество раз, `?` - поиск будет выполнятся до первой `"` двойной кавычки, т.е. в "не жадном режиме" (иначе он сработает до самой последней кавычки во всей строке).

```
// предположим, что переменная scriptTag - DOM элемент того самого скрипта
// получаем его содержимое в качестве строки
var content = scriptTag.innerHTML;

var pattern = /"market_hash_name":"(.*?)"/;
var match = content.match(pattern);

// под индексом 0 будет храниться результат всего выражения
// под индексом 1 - результат захватывающей группы (.*?)
var name = match[1];

console.log(name); // "P90 | Fallout Warning (Field-Tested)"
```

Живой пример здесь: http://jsbin.com/faposoteci/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо ! Отдельно благодарю за описание процесса !

Answer (score 0):

[Пишем javascript парсер при помощи Google Chrome Extension](http://xdan.ru/Pishem-javascript-parser-pri-pomoshhi-Google-Chrome-Extension.html)
вот почитай как сделать парсер.

Comment: Как спарсить страницу - я знаю. Но как спарсить содержимое тега `script`